# Items.ItemAdd event for Outbox folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

In an Outlook addin I'm listening to `Items.ItemAdd` event for the Outbox folder, and I inspect every email that is added to Outbox. I'm wondering whether this is guaranteed to work at all times, as I'm afraid that the email will be sent and disappear from Outbox before I have a chance to access it.

is such scenario possible? or is `ItemAdd` works in a synchronous way so I can be sure the item is still in Outbox? (I guess yes, otherwise the IDispatch pointer in the `ItemAdd` callback might be invalid)

Answer (score 1):

No, you should never touch any item in the Outbox folder - doing so will abort the message submission process.

Use the `Application.ItemSend` event instead.

Comment: I know - I re-submit the message using `SubmitMessage` (I need to work on messages in Outbox and not in earlier stage using `ItemSend`). but is it guaranteed that the item is still in Outbox?

Comment: Don't do that - by the time the event fires, chances are the message is already gone. Once again, use Application.ItemSend or Items.ItemAdd on the Sent Items folder,. Never touch anything in the Outbox folder.